# Removing memory layers as you go in QGIS Graphical Model to avoid running out of memory

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-modeler, memory-layer

I run a lot of graphical models to automate the workflow of complex tasks. Often, my workflows have 40 or 50 steps that manipulate attributes in a complex way. The graphical modeller is powerful and I love it, but it keeps each step's output available in memory for use until the very end where it garbage collects everything (Desired and expected behaviour).

The issue is, if I'm running my calculations on thousands of features, each successive step creates a new large memory layer to pass to the next step, doubling the memory requirement. This is particularly bad when using complex formulas that require upwards from 10 chained 'Field Calculator' modules. A lot of the time, my model relies upon the entire dataset, so I can't always segment my work into sub-processing cells and run each one individually. (The use of 'with_variable()' has helped compress a lot of my 'Field Calculator' chains, but is several orders of magnitude slower than having each field generated separately). As a result, I regularly exceed my 32 Gb of RAM, and about 90 Gb of page, because it produces 20 or 30 copies of my dataset each with a progressive resultant update (Usually crashing QGIS, but also occasionally blue screening, which as an old C programmer is pleasantly nostalgic).

The solution I'm searching for is a way to drop memory layers that are no longer needed as I go. I've tried (and failed) creating a python script that takes a layer as an input, then manually drops that layer from memory using:

```
### this snippet taken from inside of "def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):"

alg_params = {'INPUT': parameters['MemoryLayerToRemove'],'NAME': 'delete'}
outputs['LoadLayerIntoProject'] = processing.run('native:loadlayer', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
d = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('delete')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(d[0])
QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayer(d[0].id())
```

I placed these after each step (Setting a dependency on the following step to avoid deleting memory in use) But the process of loading it as a layer (So it can be accessed by removeMapLayer) just copies the data again. So it actually increases memory for a brief moment before releasing it again. (I've tried alternative forms of creating a QgsVectorLayer from the layer name, but I can't seem to access the memory layer without using processing.run)

I'm avoiding just doing it all in python if I can (There's a convenience in the modeller that I prefer for some of my work), but I would also be happy with a solution that uses a custom python script that could be placed in the model and re-used for each cumulative memory layer.

I'm using an older version of QGIS (3.20.1-Odense), but this also affects LTR. It's not a bug after all.